# Getting a error message after migrating to azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-migrate

[This is the warning message got before migrating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM4eW.png) Getting a error message after migrating to azure. tried to migrate a web app along with database to azure. but getting an error after login to the web app in azure. both app and database migrated to azure,but after login we cannot fetch the database

[image]

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken already?

Comment: searching for troubleshooting runtime error

Comment: I'm guessing you're not the developer of this system? Are you about to contact them at all?

Comment: not a web developer. actually, got this code from GitHub to setup a on-prem so that we can migrate to azure. so after migrating app and database, we are getting the site. but when try to login, runtime error occurs

Comment: @Dai could you please help me with this error,is it a connection string error?

Comment: Try
`<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
</system.web>` in `web.config`